# Xcode run script, is it possible to run only if a file changes?

Tags: xcode

I want to execute the script only when a certain file changes. Is this possible inside a run script phase? I don´t see anything in the docs.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

In Input Files of Run Script Phase, add the file to depend on. For example:

```
$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/$(PRODUCT_NAME).framework
```

In Output Files, add the file which the script will generate:

```
./SomeFile.txt
```

In script:

```
touch SomeFile.txt
```

Now the script will be called if SomeFile.txt is missing or is older than input file's date.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I have tried every possible thing here and nothing works. NOTHING.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommand reading http://indiestack.com/2014/12/speeding-up-custom-script-phases/ which is a great example of using this rarely known Build Phases little gem.